# What equipment is required to operate in Class "C" airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, class-c-airspace

I'm nearing my pre-solo test and I need to know this answer.

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: I don’t know.....What equipment do you need to operate in class Charlie airspace?  Where would you go to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

A radio and a transponder.

As a pre-solo student, you really **DO** need to know this. If it is not familiar to you, I strongly recommend you read up on your airspace classes.